# Running sudo scripts/bash commands on a remote

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, sudo

I need to remotely start bash scripts that perform sudo tasks, such as chmod and ntpdate and echoing to gpio.

A cron job might be the best solution for some of this, but cron is giving me headaches. I'd like to pass on this venue if I can...

I've confirmed that my scripts work locally (I can ssh into the machine and run them without a hiccup.)

However, If I try to run them remotely like so: (this is within a C++ system call)

ssh user@pc 'bash -s' < /home/user/myScript.sh

Commands with sudo fail.

sudo chmod fails with: no tty present and no askpass program specified
echo to gpio fails with: write error: Device or resource busy
sudo ntpdate fails with: no tty present and no askpass program specified

Can anyone help explain, or help me determine whats happening here?

I'm open to band-aids and different approaches, thanks!

Comment: Your attempt will also fail if `myScript.sh` attempts to read anything from *its* standard input, because the file is its own standard input. You are probably better off figuring out what your problem with `cron` is and fix that, rather than adding a layer of indirection with `ssh`.

Comment: I'm working in an isolated environment where I can't reciveve cron 'mail'.

Do you have any advice for me, relevent to troubleshooting cron?

thanks!

Comment: No, but somebody might; start with asking *that* question before abandoning `cron` altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already found the problem yourself:

> sudo chmod fails with: no tty present and no askpass program specified

If you run you shell script via ssh and the script wants to run the command `sudo`, sudo itself will ask for the users password. But the ssh session is not a tty! How should sudo now prompt for a password and how to get your password?

You can do it if you provide the password in the script ( what makes it very dangerous if someone else can read that script! )

script.sh:

> echo "your passwd" | sudo -S

As alternative solution you can run the ssh session with a more privileged user.

> ssh privileged_user@pc 'bash -s' < /home/user/myScript.sh

All that comes with some danger. Running all commands from the cript with a more privileged user can also be dangerous!

Comment: Ok, that could mean my ssh key isn't authenticating... or maybe the key requires a tty ?

I've exchanged ssh keys between the machines in an attempt to keep things relatively secure, however echoing the username and password is very helpful for troubleshooting.

Thank You!

Comment: Basically, my ssh key for the user isn't 'sticking'. I can add the key, but I still have to login. For a different user, I don't have any issues.

Comment: I'm having touble echo'ing my passwd over , hopefully I can add a flag in ssh privileged_user@pc 'bash -s' < /home/user/myScript.sh somewhere